# How to test AOV assumptions - error in plot

Tags: r

I'm trying to test AOV assumptions by plotting the residuals with the function `plot`. I'd like to test whether bacteria density is affected by temperature and my treatment. I've used the `aov` function and considered an interaction between treatment and temperature. In addition, my experimental design was performed in blocks. When I used `plot` there was an error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

## I've run the example in ?aov
npk.aov <- aov(yield ~ block + N*P*K, npk)
plot(npl.aov)
```

This example works. Both data are in a `data.frame`. The unique difference is that my independent variables are factors. But as far as I know, that's not a problem in `aov`.

May you help me with this error?

Here is a toy example:

```
block <- rep(1:7, 6)
temp <- rep(c("a", "b"), c(21, 21))
treat <- rep(rep(c("T1", "T2", "T3"), c(7, 7, 7)), 2)
density <- rnorm(42)
dat <- data.frame(block, temp, treat, density)
mod <- aov(density ~ temp*treat+Error(block/treat), data=dat)# modelo certo
plot(mod)
```

Session details:

```
platform
"x86_64-w64-mingw32"
"R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"
$nickname
"Frisbee Sailing"`
```

Comment: I don't see the example you talk about in `aov`.

Comment: ## I've run the example in ?aov
npk.aov <- aov(yield ~ block + N*P*K, npk)
plot(npl.aov)

Comment: Temperature is a continuous variable. I think you should fit a mixed effects model (e.g., have a look at package lme4).

Comment: Thank you @Roland. But in my experiment, temperature was controlled as "natural condition" (~25°) or "warmed condition" (~29°). That's the reason why I created temp "a" and "b" in my toy example.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are interested in the residuals of the "Within"  part of the model:

```
plot(residuals(mod[["Within"]])~fitted(mod[["Within"]]))
```

[image]

```
qqnorm(residuals(mod[["Within"]]))
qqline(residuals(mod[["Within"]]))
```

[image]